# Mandrill + Rails not sending via controller but sending via console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, mandrill

Hi I am having a very strange problem. I setup mandrill as per the docs and I am now unable to send mail via my controller. Even devise mails do not seem to be going.... But I am able to send it via the console!

**My Mail Config**

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
    :password  => ENV["MANDRILL_APIKEY"],
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :domain => 'yim.mydomain.org',
  }
```

**My Mailer**

```
class YimMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "notifier@yim.mydomain.org"

  def welcome_email(user, data)
    @user = user
    @data = data
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome!')
  end
end
```

**In my controller:**

```
YimMailer.welcome_email(current_user, dummydata).deliver
```

When i execute the same line via the console, it delivers. What could be the issue?

I am using rails 4

Comment: Try set config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true may help you debug mail problem, at least it can tell you if there has error in the process of sending mail

Comment: I just tried that... nothing happened. It seems to not be facing any issues. The logs are clean but it is still not delivering.

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and restarted the server (accidentally), it started working via controller too!